# How to center links in header using CSS?

Tags: css

I wanted to make the links centered on the screen rather than placed in a location to a certain number of pixels.

Here's my code:

**CSS:**

```
.HorizLinks  {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 77px; 
    left: 180px;
}
.HorizLinks ul { 
    margin: 0px; 
}
.HorizLinks li {
    margin: 0px 15px 0px 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
}
```

This is the **HTML** on the webpage:

```
<div id="container"></div>
<div id="header"></div>
<div class="HorizLinks">
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.website.com">Header Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.website.com">Header Link 2</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `text-align:center` on the `<div class="HorizLinks">`. Also, set the padding of the `ul` elements to be `0`.

Your absolute positioning of the container div is pushing the whole div to the side itself to the right side of the page, so unless you remove that, the content inside will never be able to be in the middle.

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/P3JcP/2/)

---

**CSS:**

```
.HorizLinks  {
  text-align:center;
}

.HorizLinks ul { 
  margin: 0; 
  padding:0;
}

.HorizLinks li {
  margin: 0 15px 0 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
}
```

Comment: So it would be: <div id="container"> text-align:center</div> <li><a href="http://www.website.com">Header Link 1</a>text-align:center</li> not sure about the padding